# Apostrophe in a string property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (O:Person) WHERE O.name = 'Nancy's Outbreak' RETURN O;
```

The apostrophe in "Nancy's" is breaking the statement. is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way in this use-case is to use the double-quote around your string, like this : "Nancy's Outbreak"

Otherwise you have to escape it with a backslash : 'Nancy\'s Outbreak'.

Last information, if you use query paramters, Neo4j will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try escaping the apostrophe in the name, this way:

`MATCH (O:Person) WHERE O.name = 'Nancy\'s Outbreak' RETURN O;`